# execute query in dbf from c#

Tags: c#, foxpro, dbf

i am doing a program in C# and i´m trying to execute a query in a DBF files that i think is ok but the value of the HasRows property of the DataReader is false. I think the problem is with the dates. This is my code:

```
 string Con = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\Server\ges_01";
 OleDbConnection ConnectionHandler = new OleDbConnection(Con);
ConnectionHandler.Open();

 string SQL = "SELECT codalb FROM BALBARA WHERE FECALB BETWEEN CTOD('2015/12/07') AND CTOD('2015/12/13') AND CODCLI LIKE '%9' ORDER BY CODALB"
 OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand(SQL, ConnectionHandler);
 OleDbDataReader datareader = Query.ExecuteReader();
while(datareader.Read())
{}
```

I know the rest is ok because if put `string SQL="select codalb from balbara";` Works fine.

Any one can say me what i´m doing wrong

Comment: That SQL string wont compile due to the unescaped quotes ...

Comment: You should probably use dates in the format `... WHERE FECALB BETWEEN {^2015/12/07} AND ...`

Comment: @Alex K. K i put as you suggest but not work

Comment: Have you tried to convert the date field to string using [DTOS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ? So I might try it as like: "... WHERE DTOS(fecalb) BETWEEN '20150717' AND '20151213'". The supported OLE DB commands listing is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x51c04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I dont know how to use DTOS() function

Comment: Just use your original line but make it a string literal like you did with the connection string.  `string SQL = @"SELECT codalb FROM BALBARA WHERE FECALB BETWEEN CTOD('2015/12/07') AND CTOD('2015/12/13') AND CODCLI LIKE '%9' ORDER BY CODALB"`

Comment: Also, break the code write after the SQL string is set, and see what the value is.  Check it to make sure the sytnax is valid and that it is pulling what you want.  Also, what is the datatype of FECALB in the database?  If it isn't a date, it needs to match exactly.

Comment: @kayees  you are Rigth if i put like you suggest Works fine, now i need to transform a datetime varble to that format.

@ DiscipleMichael I look the dbf file with the DBF Viewr plus program and FECALB field  is Date type

Comment: @Ion should be easy as `dateTimeVariable.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Comment: PERFECT, if you put as answer i mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the `CTOD()` function isn't supported by the [OLE DB Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x51c04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Change your query to use [`DTOS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which:

> Returns a character-string date in a yyyymmdd format from a specified
>   Date or DateTime expression.

So concluding your query might become to:

```
string SQL = String.Format(
    @"SELECT 
        codalb 
    FROM
        balbara 
    WHERE 
        DTOS(fecalb) BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'
        AND codcli LIKE '%9' 
    ORDER BY 
        codalb", 
        dateTimeVariable1.ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
        dateTimeVariable2.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

**Note 1:** check out the indenting to help you write readable code, also I suggest to write all the column/table names lowercase so you can make an easy difference what is your "data" and what is SQL.

**Note 2:** you can find offical format string examples about the `DateTime` type [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

**EDIT:** As a **good** advice in comments from @AlanB, you should always strive to use [*parametrized queries*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a string to prevent [*SQL Injection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) attacks.

A remark about the OLEDB parameters:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

And about the *order* of parameters:

> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

So all these informations given your query could look this example:

```
OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand();
Query.Connection = ConnectionHandler;
Query.CommandText = 
    @"SELECT 
        codalb 
    FROM
        balbara 
    WHERE 
        DTOS(fecalb) BETWEEN ? AND ?
        AND codcli LIKE '%9' 
    ORDER BY 
        codalb";

Query.Parameters.Add(dateTimeVariable1.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
Query.Parameters.Add(dateTimeVariable2.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
OleDbDataReader datareader = Query.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: PERFECT is just what i need